# Click on a posted news-feed Facebook will open up my iOS app on iOS 7

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I have an app on iPhone, that share a message on Facebook news-feed. It's ok. But when i open the Facebook app on the iPhone, and click on what i have shared in news-feed, it open up to my application !!?? it should open the link i have shared on Browser. My iPhone run iOS 7.0.3. In iOS 6 it's seem ok.
Does anyone deal with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve exactly your problem O.o. How did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18). section - "Communicating with other apps".

Basically, you would implement a custom url scheme for your app and when a link with your url scheme is invoked, iOS sends a message to your app to invoke itself.

Comment: Sorry, i have read it. But my problem is that: when i click on the item which i have shared on news-feed (it's a video direct link) , in iOS6 it Facebook App run to a video page, but in iOS7 it open up my Application (or Appstore if my app is not installed).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the "Deep linking" in setting of the Facebook app on my account determines the behaviour when click on the shared link (on iPhone). If i turn off "Deep linking", it will be ok.
  But now the problem is the text header of shared item is: 
      " shared a link via "
while i see some application such as Vine show on news-feed: 
      ""
(Although Vine only shares a video link, not post video to Facebook).